# How do I disable memcache?

Tags: caching

I've inherited a site that connected with memcache even though its not necessary and its not installed on the server. Although I've disabled the memcache module, 
the settings file has these lines which I cannot delete or the site stops working:

```
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/contrib/memcache/memcache.inc';
$conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';
```

I am getting this log message every two or three minutes:

> Failed to connect to memcache server: 127.0.0.1:11211

Clearing the Drupal cache and restarting Apache do not seem to fix the problem.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the site stops working when you remove those lines?  Did you do a cache clear after you removed them?

Comment: I get a lot of strange messages for example Notice: Undefined index: schema_fields_sql in /usr/local/data/www/docs/includes/entity.inc on line 298

Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to SelectQuery::fields() must be of the type array, null given, called in /usr/local/data/www/docs/includes/entity.inc on line 317 and defined in /usr/local/data/www/docs/includes/database/select.inc on line 1301

Comment: yes I did clear the cache

Comment: tried to run update, get this error Fatal error: Class 'SearchQuery' not found in /usr/local/data/www/docs/sites/all/modules/contrib/views/modules/search/views_handler_filter_search.inc on line 201

Comment: Did you restart Apache?  It really sounds like you have APC problems.

Comment: yes I did.  What is an APC problem?

Comment: APC is the opcode cache that PHP uses.  Depending on how it is configured, Apache may not detect changes in files and cause weird problems where old code gets run.

Comment: How do I change that ?

Comment: I had to use drush cc clear all for this to work. just clearing the cache from the admin page didnt work.

Comment: Please mention Drupal major version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi You have to follow below steps in order:

1. disable and uninstall module.
2. remove from settings.php and delete folder of module.
3. clear cache (make sure all tables are empty)

For users using [drush](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush):

```
drush dis memcache

The following extensions will be disabled: memcache
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you've failed to mention the module name [*Memcache*](https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache) (memcache) which is the one she needs to disable.

Comment: Thanks for making it more easy by writing name of module :)

Comment: Why is a cron run needed?

Comment: I had to use drush cc clear all for this to work. just clearing the cache from the admin page didnt work.

Comment: Please mention Drupal major version.